# Probability of joint dependent random variables

Tags: probability

I have encountered another problem from Henk Tijms "Understanding Probability" book.

> **Problem 7.19**
>   You choose a number $v$ at random from $(0,1)$. You then choose a
>   random number $w$ from $(0, 1 - v)$.
>
> What is the probability that a triangle can be formed with the side lengths $v$, $w$ and $1 - v - w$?

The answer to this question is $ln(2) - 0.5$.

I define (not sure if this is right) the sample space to be $\Omega = \{(v,w) : 0 \leq v \leq 1, 0 \leq w \leq 1 - v\}$.

By triangle inequality I have:
$$v < \frac{1}{2}, w < \frac{1}{2} \; \text{  and } \; v + w > \frac{1}{2}$$

My tutor has said that since the two random variables are dependent, I have to calculate (by Law of Total Probability):

$$\begin{align*} F_{(V,W)}(v, w) &= P(V \leq v, W \leq w) \\ &= \int_{0}^v {P(V \leq v, W \leq w | V = u)f_V (u) \; du}\end{align*}$$

But here I'm not sure how to calculate $P(V \leq v, W \leq w | V = u)$. Any ideas on how to go about this? Of course, any assistance is much appreciated.

EDIT: I should note that the chapter that I am currently in hasn't covered this. Moreover, the question gives a hint that I should "represent $w$ as $y(1-v)$, where $y$ is a random number from $(0,1)$". Is there a way to another way to approach to this question while using this hint?

Comment: $W \leq W$ looks like a mistype.  If it isn't, then $P(V \leq v, W \leq W | V = u) = P(V \leq v | V = u) $ because $W \leq W$ is always true.  Then that final expression is $1$ if $u \leq v$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @muaddib You're right, thanks for that. Should be $W \leq w$.

Comment: You can find a complete solution to the problem in [this Lecture Note](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fa2000/ppt/Lecture34.pdf) of mine.  If the included link to a .pdf file is inaccessible directly, it is Example F in Lecture 34: Jointly Continuous Random Variables III available at https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/sp2013/Slides.html.